# Android textselection when softkeyboard closes

Tags: android, listview, android-softkeyboard

My layout has a listView with some selectable textViews and an editText outside of the ListView. If the textView is in focus the softKeyboard is up . If any one the textViews in the listView is selected by longpress , I manually close the softKeyboard . The problem occurs when the layout resizes the selected text always points to the last cell in the listView and to complicate things it duplicates the last cell to the value of the selected cell.

On Selection:

```
 --aaa--
 --bbb--(selected)
 --ccc--
 ---editText--
 ---Keyboard--

After manually closing the keyboard :

---aaa--
---bbb--
---bbb--(selected and duplicated)
---editText--
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue ?

Edit:

Adding the long Press code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager).getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if(null != imm)
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        return false;  //Returning false on purpose to let the android system handle the event
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share your code, It will be useful to figure out the problem exactly. Thanks.

Comment: Well all i am doing it overriding the longPressListener of the textView and closing the softkeyboard . other than that its the same old getView code of the adapter. I have edited the question and added the long press code .